# WANT TO EDIT CHECKOUT PAGE BY ADDING A URL IN WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a url when the purchase is successfull

Now i am tring to install a plugin that it is not working

Comment: where you want to add url in checkout page?

Comment: After sucessfull purchase want to work that url

Comment: do you mean you want to redirect user on specific url(your custom thankyou page) after successful purchase right?

Comment: ys sir..i want to work that url when a successful transaction

Answer (score -1):

Okay you need to add this code in your theme function.php file and replace "https://yoursite.com/custom-url" with your site custom url

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'woo_redirectcustom');

    function woo_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $url = 'https://yoursite.com/custom-url';
        if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( $url );
            exit;
        }
    }
```